# Set left side width of mPDF header

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) for exporting contents as a PDF file. For creating header, I am using `$mpdf->SetHeader()` function like this:

```
$arr = array (
    'L' => array (
        'content' => 'Bozmadan sonra ıslah yapılamaz kuralının istisnası, ...',
        'font-size' => 10,
        'font-style' => 'B',
        'font-family' => 'serif'
    ),
    'R' => array (
        'content' => '{PAGENO}',
        'font-size' => 10,
        'font-style' => 'B',
        'font-family' => 'serif',
        'color'=>'#000000'
        ),
    'line' => 1
);
$mpdf->SetHeader($arr, 'O');
```

This gives us like this: [image]

You see, I don't want center area but it creates. How can I code for more wider left side, narrower right side and no center area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SetHTMLHeader() instead of SetHeader(), you can style it in HTML and have more control over the layout.

```
$header= '<table width="100%"><tr>  
<td width="80%">Bozmadan sonra ıslah yapılamaz kuralının istisnası, ...</td>
<td width="20%">{PAGENO}</td>
</tr></table>';
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I wonder is it possible doing with my method?